# How to run 2nd generation CPMD in CP2K?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, ab-initio-calculations, cp2k

I believe CP2K by default implements Born–Oppenheimer MD. I have seen many recent papers that use 2nd generation Car–Parrinello MD using CP2K. But I couldn't find any direct way of switching to 2nd-gen CPMD in the CP2K documentation.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if you've figured this out, now that it's been about 7 months since you asked the question?

Answer (score 5):

A similar question has been [asked](https://groups.google.com/g/cp2k/c/kkZDig18nE4) on the cp2k mailing list.

The relevant settings are the `MOTION` / `MD` / `ENSEMBLE` keyword (set to `LANGEVIN`), and the
`MOTION` / `MD` / `LANGEVIN` section.

Further suggestions from Marcella Iannuzzi in the thread:

> - Always start sgcpmd from a well converged wfn obtained along a standard BOMD run with diagonalisation and smearing
> - Let the first steps run on many scf iterations if needed, i.e., set MAX_SCF large enough
> - But use a relative large eps_scf. The wfn is not going to be optimised as in the BOMD, energy convergence  around 10^-5 is
>   desirable
> - Use FULL_ALL preconditioner + ASPC
> - Use a small time step
> - Tune properly GAMMA and NOISY_GAMMA
> - Monitor the conservation of energy and the temperature per kind or per region : TEMP_KIND

Comment: +1 is it a coincidence that you answered this the day after I wrote a comment? Or did you click "follow" on the question? Nice to have this answered!

Comment: It was a coincidence ;-)